# Cloudera Manager CDH Parcel distribution error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am trying to install a Hadoop cluster on Rackspace cloud using Cent OS 6 machines. I getting the following error during creation of new cluster from the cloudera manager. Can some one help.

Cluster Installation

Installing Selected Parcels
The selected parcels are being downloaded and installed on all the hosts in the cluster.

CDH 5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10 3 Error(s)

```
Error when distributing to vm-cdh-cluster-3 : [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
Error when distributing to vm-cdh-cluster-1 : [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
Error when distributing to vm-cdh-cluster-2 : [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
```

Comment: Can you ping those exact hostnames from the CM server host?

Comment: Yes. All the hosts are connected, /etc/hosts files updated. Instead of parcels, I used packages second time and it all worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is DNS error, Cloudera manager is not able to resolve the below hostname, you need to set up properly configure DNS servers in all nodes or modify your /etc/hosts file and add hostnames and the corresponding ip-address to that file in the below format.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
::1         localhost 
<ip-Addr1>  vm-cdh-cluster-1

<ip-Addr1>  vm-cdh-cluster-2
```

Comment: I rechecked. The host file is having the details of all hosts. This stage is after the installation of Java & cloudera-manager-agent packages on the hosts. So, I retried the whole installation to use packages instead of parcels and it has worked fine.